# popen fails due to windows 7/8 compatibility issues

Tags: python, windows-8, subprocess

I am developing a windows application in Python that launches an executable

```
with open("stdout.txt", 'w+') as out:
    p = subprocess.Popen([exe], stdout=out, stderr=STDOUT, shell=False, cwd=modelpath)
    p.communicate()
```

The application is frozen with cx_freeze and I have tried with both python 3.3 and 3.5.

With Windows 7 it works, but with Windows 8, users need to run the application in "Windows 7 compatibility mode" to avoid the executable from making the exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred at $031AEA6A :
EOutOfMemory : Out of memory
   $031AEA6A
```

Running the executable directly from cmd.exe works fine with both windows 7 and 8.

How can I make it work on Windows 8 without asking the users to run it in compatibility mode

**Edit1**

Directing the stdout and stderr to PIPE give the same error:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([exe], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False, cwd=modelpath)
stderr, stdout = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Which version of Python?  Does it work without the stdout redirection?

Comment: Thanks for the info. What is your question?

Comment: I have added the answer/question in the question